# Wrong reasoning yields $1=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fake-proofs

I was thinking about this sequence

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
n=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{\ldots}}}}}
\end{equation}
It is well known that this converges to n. For example:
$$3=\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{6+3}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{9}}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+3}}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\ldots}}}$$

The problem is when $n=0$ and $n=1$, because when we apply formula $(1)$, in both cases we get

$$\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{0+\sqrt{\ldots}}}}}$$
This yields
$$0=1$$
Can you tell me where the mistake is in the reasoning?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the nested square root has any meaning at all, it is as the limit of a sequence of finitely nested expressions.  You need to specify which ones.

For example, you might specify some initial function $a_0(n)$, and let
$a_{j+1}(n) = \sqrt{n^2 - n + a_{j}(n)}$.  You then want to prove something about the limit of $a_j(n)$ as $j \to \infty$.  It's easy to see that **if the 
limit exists** it must be $n$ or $1-n$, these being possible only if they are nonnegative (if we want everything real not allowing negative square roots), because the function $f(t) = \sqrt{n^2-n+t}$ has only those fixed points, but that doesn't say that the limit exists.

Note also that $f'(n) = 1/(2 |n|)$, while $f'(1-n) = 1/(2 |1-n|)$, so the fixed point $n$ is stable if $n > 1/2$ while $1-n$ is stable if $n < 1/2$.

Comment: Great answer. Could you clarify the "It's easy to see that if the limit exists [...]" part?

Comment: If $L = \lim_{j \to \infty} a_j(n)$ exists, then since the square root is a continuous function we have $L = \lim_{j \to \infty} a_{j+1}(n) = \lim_{j \to \infty} \sqrt{n^2-n+a_j(n)} = \sqrt{n^2 - n + \lim_{j \to \infty} a_j(n)} = \sqrt{n^2-n+L}$.  Squaring both sides, $L^2 = n^2 - n + L$, so $(L-n)(L-1+n) = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Think about how you would define the expression
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{\ldots}}}}}
\end{equation}
As others have already mentioned, you might use a sequence with recursion
$a_{k+1} = \sqrt{n^2-n+a_k}$. **However** this recursion formula by itself does **not** define a sequence. Rather, to define a sequence you must *in addition* give a recursion start $a_0$.

Now it is easy to see that if you use $a_0=n$, then for any $k>0$, $a_k=n$ as well, and thus the sequence trivially converges to $n$. However note that the expression $(1)$ does *not* imply a specific $a_0$. And that is the root of the problem.

Now consider specifically the case $n=1$. In this case, the recursion rule simplifies to $a_{k+1}=\sqrt{a_k}$.

Now consider $a_0=1$. Then it is easily seen that $a_k=1$ for all $k$. Thus the sequence converges to $1$.

However consider $a_0=0$. Then it is just as easily seen that $a_k=0$ for all $k$, and therefore the sequence converges to $0$.

Therefore the expression $(1)$ *is not well defined* unless you explicitly provide a rule how to choose $a_0$ (or provide another explicit way to interpret that expression; the point being that whatever you choose as meaning must be *completely* specified).

Answer (score 4):

- The expression on the right hand side is not well-defined since one can not tell if such object exists or not:
  \begin{equation}\tag{1}
  n=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{\ldots}}}}}
  \end{equation}
  On has to give a precise *definition* of the $\sqrt{\cdots}$ part. "Keep going on like this", for instance, is not a mathematical definition.
- > "That is, well known, converges to n."

  Excuse my ignorance, I don't think it is a "well known" fact. And I don't even think it is a correct mathematical statement. Again, one needs to define "converges" carefully.
- > For example:
  >   $$3=\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{6+3}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{9}}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+3}}=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\ldots}}}$$

  "For example" is not a proof.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at $(1)$, say we set
$$x=\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{n^2-n+\sqrt{\dots}}}}$$
Because this goes on forever, we clearly have that
$$x^2-(n^2-n)=x$$
Solving this using the quadratic formula yields $x=1-n$ or $x=n$. At this point, we simply choose whatever makes since (i.e. if $n>1$, then $x$ is clearly positive so we take $x=n$). In our case of $n=1$, it makes sense to have $x=1-n$.

Answer (score 2):

We can write $S_{k+1} = \sqrt{n^2 - n + S_k}$.

Assuming the sequence converges to some $L$ (which you can show since it's increasing and bounded by $n$) you can solve to get 
$$L^2 - L - (n - n^2) = 0,
$$
 which gives solutions of $L = n$ or $L = 1 - n$.

Comment: If I choose $S_0=n^10$ the sequence clearly is *not* increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Formulae $1$ naturally does not converge to $1$. If a formula works for almost all $n$, it need not work for all $n$, right? So it does not make sense  to apply the formula  at $n=1$, although it converges everywhere else.

To give another example, suppose that I am given this  sequence:$$
\sqrt{n^2 - bn + b\sqrt{n^2-bn + b\sqrt{n^2-bn + b\sqrt{n^2-bn + \ldots}}}}
$$

Then, it is easy to see that this sequence converges to $n$ for almost all $n$, since we just have $n = \sqrt{n^2-bn+bn}$. However, at $n=b$, we see that this just simplifies to $0$. Now, we would like to say that $b=0$, but then this is not true, is it? (We could have chosen $b$ randomly, you did it for $b=1$).

Hence, the up shot of the whole thing is that the formula doesn't work in certain cases, although it may work in comprehensive generality.